# How to stop the OMPL planner after the first solution is found?

Tags: c++

I'm using an RRTstar planner from OMPL. 
To solve it I use:

```
ompl::base::PlannerStatus solved = setup.solve(time);
```

`solve()` takes a double time value to specify the requested running time of algorithm. How can I request stopping the algorithm right after the first valid solution is found ?

An instance of the class `ompl::base::PlannerTerminationCondition` can be passed to `solve()` as well, but I'm not sure how to use it and whether it would be used in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, Mark Moll answered this question in an email to me.
Most planners in OMPL stop after the first solution is found. But the asymptotically optimal planners like RRT* try to optimize the path as long as time permits. This behavior can be changed by calling `setCostThreshold` with a large value of the optimization objective (by default path length is minimized).